# Postgres Pattern matching with LIKE/ILIKE on all JSONB fields

Tags: postgresql

I have a column, called `metadata` on my table (say `trips`) which is of JSONB type. I'd like to pattern match/search on all values of `metadata`.

For example, one of the entires of the `metadata` column is of the form:

```
{"city": "London", "trip_id": 2075209, "store_id": 108, "driver_id": 1166061,  "driver_name": "Jon Doe", "track_back_order": false}
```

I'd like to fetch all records with city as London. I've tried to cast the metadata column into text in my `WHERE` clause with

```
WHERE trips.metadata::TEXT ILIKE 'London'
```

which returns 0 results.

But searching at a field level works, for example this `WHERE` clause returns the appropriate results:

```
WHERE trips.metadata->>'city' ILIKE 'London'
```

But since the keys of the metadata column can be arbitrary, I cannot do the above query for each field. Any ideas on how I can solve for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ILIKE` or `LIKE` without any wildcards is the same as `=`.

So  - ignoring case sensitivity -  `trips.metadata::TEXT ILIKE 'London'` is essentially the same as `trips.metadata::TEXT = 'London'`

Obviously that doesn't work.

You can use a JSON path expression if you want to iterate over all keys:

```
where metadata @@ '$.* like_regex "London" flag "i"'
```